# PHash компиляция и установка

Tags: php, расширения, компиляция

В общем, уже второй день борюсь с компиляцией [pHash](https://github.com/sdepold/pHash/tree/master/bindings/php), но оно всё никак не идёт. C линуксом в целом проблемы, но делаю вроде бы всё по инструкции, в результате как была куча файлов, так и остаётся куча файлов. Файла расширения, который я потом могу добавить в `php.ini`, нет.

Может, кто пользовался этой библиотекой и у кого-то остался готовый файл, который нужно только подключить, поделитесь, пожалуйста. Ну или помогите скомпилировать эту заразу.

Нужно только расширение для получения перцептивного хэша от изображений, все остальные модули не нужны.

**Обновление**

Сейчас Ubuntu. Вообще не понимаю разработчика, раз уж библиотека идёт в открытом доступе, то почему бы просто не выложить .dll файл на гитхаб вместо кучи файлов, которые надо ещё собирать и компилировать. :(

Comment: @Floyat, что за дистрибутив линукса?

Answer (score 1):

[[@Floyat](/users/24295/floyat)](/users/24295/floyat), потому что гитхаб - это хранилище именно исходного кода, там и не должно быть никаких бинарников.

Я не могу скомпилировать из-за отсутствия `php_logos.h`, судя по гуглу, этот файл выпилили в свежих версиях, если до выходных ничего не образуется - попробуйте поднять топик, я поиграюсь со старыми версиями/if'ами.

А вообще вот [здесь](http://www.phash.org/download/) в .tar.gz:/bindings/php/modules я вижу вполне себе .so-файл.

**Обновление**

Если у вас убунту, то вы откуда-то не оттуда взяли информацию о том, что вам нужен .dll. .dll нужен для windows-машин, на линуксе используются .so. Скорее всего, конкретно эта .so'шка несовместима с текущей версией PHP и скомпилирована для какого-нибудь 5.3.0.

Comment: Но ведь нужен именно .dll файл, .so сервер не принимает у меня, только что проверил. Пустые ворнинги вылазят.

Comment: У меня и убунту и винда. Хоть на чём-нибудь бы скомпилировать. Весь Интернет обошёл, нигде рабочего расширения нет. А аналогов pHash для сравнения изображений не нашёл. Просто мой самописный скрипт на php работает отвратительно, нужно что-то более мощное.